# Is there a way with JPA CriteriaBuilder to fetch a non-entity object?

Tags: jpa, criteria-api, openjpa

Say that I want to do a select from 2 databases.  Database1 has fields A, B and C.  Database2 has fields D, E and F.  I have a POJO that consists of fields X, Y and Z.  I want to write a CriteriaBuilder query to select all of the B, D and F fields in the result set and map them to the fields X, Y and Z in my POJO, returning a list of my POJO objects. Is this possible?  I can do this with a native query, but I don't want to use native queries.

Comment: Do you have two databases, or two tables? JPA works with entities. Not with tables. Show us these entities and their mapping.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  It is 2 tables...not 2 databases.  Entity1 is mapped to Table1 and contains fields A, B and C.  Entity2 is mapped to Table2 and contains fields D, E and F.  I want to select from these, but I want my result to be a list of a 3rd non-entity POJO.  I want my POJO to contain 3 fields - X, Y and Z.  I want these 3 fields to contain the query results from Entity1.B, Entity2.D and Entity2.F, respectively.  And I want to be able to execute the query and get this resultlist with CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use the JPA 2.0 CriteriaBuilder to fetch a list of non-entity objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551214/can-i-use-the-jpa-2-0-criteriabuilder-to-fetch-a-list-of-non-entity-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the below query to return a entity initialized by other entities :

```
SELECT NEW com.package.Entity3(e1.b, e2.d, e2.f) FROM Entity e1, Entity e2;
```

Then you have to provide a constructor with similar signature as in query, where you can set the field values as required.

```
public Entity3(int b, int d, int f){
   x = b;
   y = d;
   z = f;
}
```