# Can I use the JPA 2.0 CriteriaBuilder to fetch a list of non-entity objects?

Tags: jpa, openjpa, nativequery

I asked a similar question to this, but I didn't provide good details, so I am re-asking the question with better details.

I have 2 tables that look like this:

```
Table1
    A
    B
    C
    PK

Table2
    D
    E
    F
    PK
```

These 2 tables have JPA entities associated with them as follows (I'm leaving out the annotations for brevity):

```
Entity1
    {
        String a;
        String b;
        String c;
        int PK;
    }
Entity2
    {
        String d;
        String e;
        String f;
        int PK;
    }
```

I also have a simple POJO that I am using (not mapped to any table) as follows:

```
MyPOJO
    {
        String x;
        String y;
        String z;
    }
```

I currently am using JPA's native SQL functionality to return a result set of type List and the query looks something like this:

```
SELECT A as x, D as y, F as z from Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.PK = Table2.PK
```

My question is, can I do this using CriteriaBuilder?  If so, how?  I am trying to stay away from native queries.  I am using OpenJPA, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using pure JPA2.

Try following article (section CriteriaBuilder's construct)

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#SELECT_in_Criteria_Queries_